# CodePen -> getJSON works only in IE but does not in Chrome or FF, why is that?

Tags: getjson

please help me with a tip
I have created this pen https://codepen.io/Dimas_X/pen/yKEzBE?editors=0010

```
$(function() { 
  const func = function(){
        let counter = 0;
        return function(){
        $.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1",
          function(data){
            $('p').html(data[0].content + '<p>'+ data[0].title  +'</p>');
          });
          counter++;
          $('span').html(counter);
       }
  }
  $('button').on('click', func());
 // $('button').trigger('click');
});
```

and it works properly only in IE. In Chrome it works when devTools is open. 
Counter of clicks works, mean click event works.
There are no any mistakes in console. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing the request get made several times within the network tab of firefox and chrome, but the response is the same every time.   Your application is populating the first response correctly, it just seems as if the first request is being cached.

If you have access to the web server code, it look like wordpress is being used because of `wp json`. You should add the following code to ensure the response isn't being cached

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Once that is Done I think your code should work just fine.

You can also on the frontend perform a query to a "unique url" each time by making the url `.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1?_=" + new Date().getTime()` to prevent caching

Comment: Hi @Charles, thank you for your response. I appreciate your help. The point is that I am on a client side only. I have no access to the server. I just wonder why this code does not work properly as should. I thought that is my mistake somewhere in the code or in codepen settings

Comment: @Dimas_X since you only have access to the frontend you can make the request unique each time.  To do that instead of the static url make it 

`.getJSON("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1?_=" + new Date().getTime()`

Comment: it works, many thanks, but could you explain what does it mean "?_=" ? another parameter in get request? does it consider by the server?

Comment: @Dimas_X it just adds the parameter of `_` You can change that to say `version` or `time`.  This just allows the browser to make a new request each time and prevent caching

Comment: Now it's clear, thanks again for your fast response!